# Can't create widgets inside other widgets - Attempting to set QLayout "" on "", which already has a layout

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to create a QDockWidget, which contains another QWidget, which in turn contains other QWidgets.

My code is below.  It produces the error message 'QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on "", which already has a layout'.

The problem seems to be that I'm setting a layout inside the 'ResultBox' QWidget, which already has one inherited from somewhere.  How do I stop it inheriting one, or else how do I delete the inherited one so I can replace it?

Alternatively, is there a way I can add new widgets inside 'ResultBox' without using a layout?

I've tried reading the answers to similar questions but haven't been able to resolve my problem.

```
class InfoWidget(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QDockWidget.__init__(self, 'Information')
        container = QWidget() # new container without an inherited layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        heading = QLabel()
        heading.setText('My Heading')
        layout.addWidget(heading)

        layout.addSpacing(INFO_SPACE)

        resultBox = ResultBox()
        layout.addWidget(resultBox)

        container.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWidget(container)

class ResultBox(QWidget):
    def __init__(self): 
        QWidget.__init__(self)

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        shortResultLine = QWidget()
        layout.addWidget(shortResultLine) 

        quickResultLine = QWidget()
        layout.addWidget(quickResultLine) 

        self.setLayout(layout)
```

Comment: What is all that junk doing in `paintEvent`?! Please read the [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#paintEvent) before randomly overriding protected methods.

Comment: I want it to repaint the 'results'.  (I haven't included in the code above what 'shortResultsLine' and 'quickResultsLine' actually contain - they draw lines and text which change depending on other things.)

Comment: None of what you currently have in `paintEvent` has got anything to do with painting widgets. Please do some basic research.

Comment: Ekhumoro - what I actually have in 'paintEvent' is stuff like this: "shortResultLine = ResultLine(DISTANCE_COLOR, 'Shortest route', self.bikeWindow, 'shortestPathMessage')".  That is, a call to another class which creates a QWidget.  Not relevant to my question.  My code works if ResultBox is a QDockWidget, but not if it's a QWidget.  Hence, I'm asking why I can't create QWidgets inside other QWidgets.  If you happen to know the answer and are willing to share it, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: The entire problem with your code is the way you are using `paintEvent`, which is completely and utterly wrong (whether it seems to "work" by accident is beside the point). Depending on the platform, the `paintEvent` may be called repeatedly every time you click/move the mouse, or raise/lower the window, or change focus, etc, etc, etc. It's used for low-level painting using [QPainter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#details), not creating entire widgets and layouts. Until you accept this very basic point, there is really nothing more that can be said.

Comment: OK, I see.  So if I want widgets to appear in a box, or not, depending on circumstances existing at the time of a paint event, I need to find a way to do it other than creating them in paintEvent.  Thanks.